# CSS ::before pseudo-element not respecting z-index stacking context

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Why does my `::before` pseudo-element not sit behind it's parent? I am creating a new stacking context and adding a `z-index` of -1.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/afewgoodben/pen/OJjLaWg)

```
  .panda {
    position: relative;
    border: 1.5vmin solid black;
    width: 45vmin;
    height: 45vmin;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;

    &:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 15vmin;
      height: 15vmin;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: -4vmin;
      left: -2.1vmin;
      box-shadow: 30vmin 0 #000;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your panda's eye and nose are nice

Comment: Thanks, wish I could get the ears behind his head.

Comment: Could you tell about this line `border-radius: 50% 50% 48% 52% / 21% 21% 79% 79%;` . And which part does create the ears

Comment: The part that creates the ears is the .panda:before

Comment: Yup found that and solution is to use `::after` in CSS(you know about CSS) but can you tell about the `border-radius: 50% 50% 48% 52% / 21% 21% 79% 79%;`

Comment: That border-radius is creating the oval shape of the eyes.

Comment: Yes that's right but as `border-radius` property is like this : `border-radius: top right bottom left` what are the value work with `/` after `/`

Comment: You can finer tune the individual corners of the border with those extra values.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::after` inserts its content immediately before the end of the tag it's applied to but still inside the tag, z-index couldn't be lower than the z-index of the tag, so your approach won't work. But you could do `::after` to the parent tag, which in your case has class 'circle'. As the inserted content will be relative to the wrapping tag, you should adjust the position of the contend related to this tag.

See a codepen example:

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/librasoft/pen/VwzZgwE)

See a snippet example here:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.canvas {
    background: #573d0e;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  .circle {
    width: 70vmin;
    height: 70vmin;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
  }

  .circle:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 15vmin;
      height: 15vmin;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: 10vmin;
      left: 12vmin;
      box-shadow: 30vmin 0 #000;
    }

.panda {
    position: relative;
    border: 1.5vmin solid black;
    width: 45vmin;
    height: 45vmin;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;

  }

  .eyes {
      position: relative;

    > * {
        position: absolute;
        width: 11vmin;
        height: 15vmin;
        background: #000;
        border-radius: 70px / 100px;
        left: 8.7vmin;
        top: 9vmin;
        transform: rotate(12deg);

        &:before,
        &:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
        }

        &:before {
            width: 4vmin;
            height: 6vmin;
            background: white;
            border-radius: 76px / 100px;
            left: 5vmin;
            top: 3.2vmin;
            transform: rotate(348deg);
        }

        &:after {
          width: 2vmin;
          height: 3vmin;
          background: black;
          border-radius: 76px / 100px;
          left: 6.3vmin;
          top: 5vmin;
          transform: rotate(348deg);
        }
    }

    :last-child {
        transform: scale(-1, 1) rotate(12deg);
        left: 22.3vmin;
    }
  }

  .snout {
        position: absolute;
        width: 25vmin;
        height: 18vmin;
        top: 23vmin;
        left: 8.5vmin;
        bottom: 5vmin;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1.5vmin solid black;

        &:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 1.5vmin;
            height: 5vmin;
            left: 10vmin;
            top: 7vmin;
            background: black;
        }
  }

  .nose {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10vmin;
    height: 7vmin;
    left: 5.7vmin;
    top: 0.5vmin;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 48% 52% / 21% 21% 79% 79%;
  }

  .mouth {
        position: absolute;
        width: 9.6vmin;
        height: 5vmin;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-bottom: 1.5vmin solid black;
        bottom: 1.6vmin;
        left: 6vmin;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="canvas">
        <div class="circle">
            <div class="panda">
                <div class="eyes">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="snout">
                    <div class="nose"></div>
                    <div class="mouth"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. So there's really no way to create a new stacking context from an elements direct parent?

Comment: I don't think there's a way in case of absolute positioning ... not 100% sure, it might work in some browsers but it won't be a stable solution

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panda {
    position: relative;
    border: 1.5vmin solid black;
    width: 45vmin;
    height: 45vmin;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    
    
  }
  .panda:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 15vmin;
      height: 15vmin;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: -4vmin;
      left: -2.1vmin;
      box-shadow: 30vmin 0 #000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="panda"></div>
```

Comment: Nice , I was just doing that but can't find a way in SCSS(or SASS don't know)

Comment: Looks like it's working in the code editor here, but not in codepen?
https://codepen.io/afewgoodben/pen/OJjLaWg

Comment: Add z-index:1 to your circle class and remove z-index-2 from panda

Comment: And say with a green tick that this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Element always use the z-index of the parent. If a parent div has a z-index, all childs **can't** be set on a lower z-index. The minimum z-index always will be the parent one.

For you panda, the best solution is create a special div for ears out of ".panda" :

CSS :

```
.ears{
    position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15vmin;
  height: 15vmin;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 8vmin;
  left: 12vmin;
  box-shadow: 30vmin 0 #000;
}
```

HTML :

```
   <div class="canvas">
        <div class="circle">
          <div class="ears"></div>
            <div class="panda">
                <div class="eyes">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="snout">
                    <div class="nose"></div>
                    <div class="mouth"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can fix ears on .circle. Live example : https://codepen.io/camillewemajin/pen/ExvYOBV

Comment: Thanks but you are supposed to be able to create a new stacking context of the `:before` by setting your pseudoelement to position: absolute;

Comment: You're right, set .circle on position relative ! Live example : https://codepen.io/camillewemajin/pen/ExvYOBV